# Implementing "cut" in a recursive descent parser

Tags: parsing, prolog, backtracking, peg, prolog-cut

I'm implementing a PEG parser generator in Python, and I've had success so far, except with the "cut" feature, of which whomever knows Prolog must know about.

The idea is that after a cut (`!`) symbol has been parsed, then no alternative options should be attempted at the same level.

```
expre = '(' ! list ')' | atom.
```

Means that after the `(` is seen, the parsing must succeed, or fail without trying the second option.

I'm using Python's (very efficient) exception system to force backtracking, so I tried having a special `FailedCut` exception that would abort the enclosing choice, but that didn't work.

Any pointers to how this functionality is implemented in other parser generators would be helpful.

Maybe the problem I've had has been lack of locality. The code generated for the left part of the rule would be something like:

```python
cut_seen = False
try:
    self.token('(')
    cut_seen = True 
    self.call('list')
    self.token(')')
except FailedParse as e:
    if cut_seen:
         raise FailedCut(e)
    raise
```

Then the code generated for the choice (`|`) operator will skip the following choices if it catches a `FailedCut`. What I mean by lack of locality is that the choice catching the `FailedCut` may be deep up in calls, thus having an effect too-difficult to discern.

Instead of making the code generated for sequences try to inform enclosing choices of *cuts*, I could make the code generated for choices beware of them. That would make the scope of cuts very local, unlike Prolog's, but good enough for what I want in a PEG parser, which is to commit to an option after a certain token sequence has been seen, so the error reporting is refers to that location in the source, instead of to another location where some other option might have been available.

It just occurred to me that if the code generated for a rule/predicate catches `FailedCut` and translates it into a normal `FailedParse` exception, then the cuts will have the right scope.

In reference to @false's question, here's a complete example of what I want to work:

```python
start = expre ;

expre = named | term ;

named = word ':' ! term;

term = word ;
```

In that grammar, `word` can be reached through `named` or `term`, but I would like the parser to commit to the `named` branch after it has seen the `:`.

### The Solution

To be fair, I've published my work so far at https://bitbucket.org/apalala/grako/.

In the final solution, sequences are enclosed with this context manager:

```python
@contextmanager
def _sequence(self):
    self._push_cut()
    try:
        yield
    except FailedParse as e:
        if self._cut():
            self.error(e, FailedCut)
        else:
            raise
    finally:
        self._pop_cut()
```

And options in a choice function are enclosed with this:

```python
@contextmanager
def _option(self):
    p = self._pos
    try:
        self._push_ast()
        try:
            yield
            ast = self.ast
        finally:
            self._pop_ast()
        self.ast.update(ast)
    except FailedCut as e:
        self._goto(p)
        raise e.nested
    except FailedParse:
        self._goto(p)
```

Which forces an exit out of the choice instead of a return to try the next option.

The cuts themselves are implemented thus:

```python
def _cut(self):
    self._cut_stack[-1] = True
```

The full source code may be found on [Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/apalala/grako/src).

Comment: I don't know how you used exceptions, thus my advice could be useless.... Take a look at cut implementation of [YieldProlog](http://yieldprolog.sourceforge.net/tutorial2.html). Do you think is relevant to you?

Comment: My parser generator uses exceptions in the straight-forward way: a statement either parses the intended input, or it raises an exception. My idea is the approach allows much more straight-forward code (no `if-and-and-and-else`s), and faster recovery at the point where recovery can be done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution proposed at the end of my question worked:

```
cut_seen = False
try:
    self.token('(')
    cut_seen = True 
    self.call('list')
    self.token(')')
except FailedParse as e:
    if cut_seen:
         raise FailedCut(e)
    raise
```

Then, any time a choice or optional is evaluated, the code looks like this:

```
p = self.pos
try:
   # code for the expression
except FailedCut:
    raise
except FailedParse:
    self.goto(p)
```

**Edit**

The actual solution required keeping a "cut stack". The [source code](https://bitbucket.org/apalala/grako/src/ed78d7a20b002bc65124b5125d982f40fab10d02/grako/parsing.py?at=default) is int Bitbucket.

Answer (score 3):

In a Prolog with ISO Prolog's exception handling (`catch/3` and `throw/1`), a cut could be implemented as:

```
cut. % Simply succeeds
cut :-
   throw(cut). % on backtracking throws an exception
```

This would require to catch that exception at appropriate places. For example, each goal (that is non-terminal) of a user defined predicate could now be wrapped with:

```
catchcut(Goal) :-
   catch(Goal,cut,fail).
```

This is not the most efficient way to implement cut since it does not free resources upon success of `!`, but it might be sufficient for your purposes. Also, this method now might interfere with user-defined uses of `catch/3`. But you probably do not want to emulate the entire Prolog language in any case.

Also, consider to use Prolog's [dcg](/questions/tagged/dcg)-grammars directly. There is a lot of fine print that is not evident when implementing this in another language.

Comment: Remember that I'm working in Python! What you describe was kind of what I attempted: wrap the sequence following the cut in a pass/throw structure, but it didn't work, probably because the generated code was too complicated. All I need is for a choice to fail once an option that was committed through a cut failed.

Comment: @Apalala: This is a clear misunderstanding: Not  the "sequence following the cut" is protected with an exception handler, but the non-terminal where the cut occurs in.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you're thinking Prolog, and the cut protects the particular clause from backtracking, because the non-terminal may be the left hand side of several clauses. I think I need to post an example.

Comment: @Apalala: You need to have some backtracking mechanism in your implementation. Note that it is usually next-to trivial implementing backtracking with loops in procedural languages-as long as there is no interruption due to cut. With the method I showed you, you can even handle this. Not very efficiently, but probably good enough for parsing.

Comment: I understand, but this is is a PEG parser generator. Once `A` succeeds in `(A|B)`, there's no trying `B`, even if there's a failure ahead. What I need is a cut failure of `A` to avoid trying `B`.

Answer (score 1):

Just read it.

I'd suggested a deep `cut_seen` (like with modifying parser's state) and a save and restore state with local variables. This uses the thread's stack as "`cut_seen` stack".

But you have another solution, and I'm pretty sure you're fine already.

BTW: nice compiler – it's just the opposite of what I'm doing with pyPEG so I can learn alot ;-)

Comment: I though about having `cut_seen` be a class attribute, but then I'd loose the desired local effect: a `cut+fail` should affect only the closest choice in the runtime stack, and a `cut+success` should eventually clear the cut. I'm updating the question with the code relevant to the solution.

Comment: **Grako** generates a model of the parser like [pyPEG](http://fdik.org/pyPEG/), and the model generates the top-down parser source-code. The model can also parse, but the nodes themselves do the parsing, which is very efficient, unlike in **pyPEG**, where an external parser visits the model using `isinstance()` to decide what to do with each node. See [this](https://bitbucket.org/apalala/grako/src/479b7c1b80287616532293d144a9c42ee4b2af7c/grako/grammars.py?at=default). The reason **Grako** generates a functional top-down parser is because model-based parsing engines are too difficult to debug.

Comment: The reason why I'm not generating a parser is that I need to modify the grammar while runtime. That would require to regenerate a parser each time it is modified.

The debugging is not too difficult, though, because there is a generic parse function only. There is no need to debug generated functions.

Comment: I understand, but you would gain plenty in performance if you made the grammar model objects parse their own stuff instead of having the ``parse()`` function make decisions based on their types.

Comment: You're completely right. But pyPEG has a special purpose: I need it to bootstrap Intrinsic, a language which is requiring me to have pyPEG as an interpreter and not generating out anything. This makes pyPEG extremely flexible and easy, while Grako will be faster without any doubts. I like your idea of having a cut in PEG grammars, though.

Comment: Want I meant to say is that pyPEG would be much faster if each node created while constructing the grammar did it's own parsing. It would be moving code out of the `parse()` method, and into `parse()` methods of the nodes, which already know they're type. It's the [Composite Design Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern).

Comment: Yes. That would require me to implement monkey patching. You remember, the grammar will change while runtime. Because I wanted to avoid self modifying code, I was setting aside compiling at all.